# Set radio button checked with AJAX response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to set a radio button in my form; it has to be checked with the values coming from an AJAX response.

My AJAX response is `response.drive`. "Manual" or "Auto" could be its value.

**UPDATE:**
So I tried it some different ways, but I couldn't figure this out.

One way :

```
if(response.drive=="Manual") {
    .find('[name=drive]')[0].checked = true         
} else {
    .find('[name=drive]')[1].checked = true
}
```

Another way:

```
.find("input:radio[name='drive'][value='"+ response.drive +"']")[0].checked = true.end()
```

This is how my ajax success function use to populate the form values.

```
.success(function(response) {
                    // Populate the form fields with the data returned from server
                    response = jQuery.parseJSON(response)
                    $('#editVehicle')

                            .find('[name="vehicle_id"]').val(response.vehicle_id).end()
                            .find('[name="vehicle_name"]').val(response.vehicle).end()
                            .find('[name="seats"]').val(response.seats).end()
                            .find('[name="luggage"]').val(response.luggage).end()
                            .find('[name="doors"]').val(response.doors).end()
                            .find('[name="emission"]').val(response.emission).end()

                            //.find('[name="drive"]').val(response.drive).prop("checked",true).end()
                            //.find('[name="aircon"]').val(response.aircon).prop("checked",true).end()
                            //.find("input:radio[name='drive'][value='"+ response.drive +"']")[0].checked = true.end()

                            //if(response.drive=="Manual"){
                .find('[name=drive]')[0].prop('checked').end()
                            //}else{
                                //.find('[name=drive]')[1].prop('checked')
                            //} 

                            .find('[name="rental"]').val(response.price).end();

                    // Show the dialog
---- -
---- 
---
```

This is HTML for radio button :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Transmission :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="drive" id="" value="1"> Manual
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="drive" id="" value="2"> Auto
        </label>                                                                
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: use `prop()` function. try `.find('[name=drive]')[0].prop('checked')`

Comment: @TamilSelvan, Yes I tried it something like this - `.find("input:radio[name='drive'][value='"+ response.drive +"']").prop("checked",true)`. But its not working for me.

Comment: @TamilSelvan, This is how I tried it. `if(response.drive=="Manual"){
                .find('[name=drive]')[0].prop('checked').end()     
       }else{
        .find('[name=drive]')[1].prop('checked').end()
       } `

Comment: But still not working

Comment: Provide some html output

Comment: Your code appears to have a lot of syntax errors. Just so we're sure you're not just abbreviating your code, please create a demo either here or jsfiddle.net.

Comment: try `$('#editVehicle').find(':radio[name=drive][value="1"]').prop('checked', true);`

Comment: @TamilSelvan, Can we chat regarding this? Thank you.

Comment: ok let discuss in chat @user3733831

Comment: @TamilSelvan, How can log into chat?

Comment: In your profile, there is the chat link, click it and create a new chat link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77429/discussion-between-tamil-selvan-and-user3733831).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
$('#editVehicle').find(':radio[name=drive][value="1"]').prop('checked', true);
```

Sample:

---

```js
$(function() {
  response = {
    "vehicle_id": 2,
    "vehicle": "RENAULT TWINGO2798",
    "seats": 43,
    "luggage": 5,
    "doors": 34,
    "emission": 455,
    "drive": "Manual",
    "aircon": "Yes",
    "price": "435.000"
  };
  
  console.log(response.drive);
  
  if (response.drive == 'Manual')
    $('#editVehicle').find(':radio[name=drive][value="1"]').prop('checked', true);
  else
    $('#editVehicle').find(':radio[name=drive][value="2"]').prop('checked', true);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="editVehicle">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Transmission :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="drive" id="" value="1">Manual
      </label>
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="drive" id="" value="2">Auto
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit:

Change it.

```
if (response.drive == 'Manual'){
                                .find(':radio[name=drive][value="1"]').prop('checked', true)
                            } else {
                                .find(':radio[name=drive][value="2"]').prop('checked', true)
                            }
```

to

```
if (response.drive == 'Manual'){
                                $('#editVehicle').find(':radio[name=drive][value="1"]').prop('checked', true)
                            } else
                                $('#editVehicle').find(':radio[name=drive][value="2"]').prop('checked', true)
                            }
```

---

```
$('.editVehicle').on('click', function() {
            // Get the record's ID via attribute
            var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
            var vehicleId = 'vehicleId=' + id;

            $.ajax({
                    url: './includes/ajaxprocess_edit_vehicles.php',
                    method: 'post',
                    data: vehicleId
            }).success(function(response) {
                    // Populate the form fields with the data returned from server
                    response = jQuery.parseJSON(response)
                    $('#editVehicle')

                            .find('[name="vehicle_id"]').val(response.vehicle_id).end()
                            .find('[name="vehicle_name"]').val(response.vehicle).end()
                            .find('[name="seats"]').val(response.seats).end()
                            .find('[name="luggage"]').val(response.luggage).end()
                            .find('[name="doors"]').val(response.doors).end()
                            .find('[name="emission"]').val(response.emission).end();

                            if (response.drive == 'Manual'){
                                $('#editVehicle').find(':radio[name=drive][value="1"]').prop('checked', true)
                            } else {
                                $('#editVehicle').find(':radio[name=drive][value="2"]').prop('checked', true)
                            }   



    $('#editVehicle').find('[name="rental"]').val(response.price).end();

                        // Show the dialog
                        bootbox
                                .dialog({
                                        title: 'Edit This Vehicle',
                                        message: $('#editVehicle'),
                                        show: false // We will show it manually later
                                })
                                .on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
                                        $('#editVehicle')
                                                .show()                       // Show the edit form
                                                .formValidation('resetForm'); // Reset form
                                })
                                .on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {
                                        // Bootbox will remove the modal (including the body which contains the edit form)
                                        // after hiding the modal
                                        // Therefor, we need to backup the form
                                        $('#editVehicle').hide().appendTo('body');
                                })
                                .modal('show');
                });
        });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But when I trying this there is a sysntaxError. Message is `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.'
 

.find(':radio[name=drive][value="1"]').prop('checked', true`

Comment: I am not sure what is the issue it has. This is my code for this - http://pastebin.com/trvH9q8a\

Comment: Then I can get this error `
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
 

$('#editVehicle').find('[name="rental"]').val(response.price`

Comment: When I removing this code block `
       if (response.drive == 'Manual'){
        $('#editVehicle').find(':radio[name=drive][value="1"]').prop('checked', true)
       } else
        $('#editVehicle').find(':radio[name=drive][value="2"]').prop('checked', true)
       }   ` Then I can NOT get this that systaxError

Answer (score 1):

You can give an id to each radiobutton and then:

```
$("#drive_1").attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Comment: I need to do this with an ajax response.

Comment: Can you first check if the syntax is correct and if the ajax call is being made? and if it's successful?

(...)
        success: function(data) {
           $("#drive_1").attr('checked', 'checked');
          console.log("Data retrieved successfuly!");
        }
      });

(...)

Comment: Yes my ajax call is correct and is working. This is how my response array work `{"vehicle_id":2,"vehicle":"RENAULT TWINGO2798","seats":43,"luggage":5,"doors":34,"emission":455,"drive"
:"Manual","aircon":"Yes","price":"435.000"}`

Comment: Ok. Now can you test if the jquery function is working OUTSIDE the ajax call ? because it works for me...try to log whatever jquery is 'catching'