# How i pass the dropdown value to ajax controller?

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

This is my dropdown box:

[image]

I am sending drop down value to ajax controller function to get some value.But the value is not passed correctly and i can't find the error;

My ajax code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.states').change(function(){
        $id = $('.states').val();        
        $.ajax({
            type    : "POST",
            url     : "<?php echo base_url();?>Reports/Fetch_Item",
            data    :{id:$(this).val()},                        
            success : function (data) {
                alert(data);
                var obj=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            }           
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

My controller code;

```
public function Fetch_Item(){
    $name = $this->input->post('id');
    $result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM acc_master WHERE accName = '$name'")->row();
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Front drop down box :

```
<div id="item3">
Party Name Selection:
<select multiple="multiple" style="width:400px;height:205px;"  name="PName"id="Name" class="form-control states">   
<option value=""></option>
</select> 
<?php echo form_error('Area', '<div class="text-danger">', '</div>'); ?><br><br><br></div>
```

Dropdown ajax code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>Reports/get_countries1",
        data:{id:$(this).val()}, 
        beforeSend :function(){
        $('.states').find("option:eq(0)").html("Please wait..");
            },                         
        success: function (data) {
    $('.states').find("option:eq(0)").html("");
    var obj=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    $(obj).each(function()
    {
        var option = $('<option />');
        option.attr('value', this.value).text(this.label);           
        $('.states').append(option);
    });  
}});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your select box has multiple option? Please share your select box HTML code also

Comment: that value also passing through ajax only

Comment: but during alert the selected value  is shown only selected value then how it is not passing to controller

Comment: `$(this).val()` returns an array not a signal value

Comment: okey then what i have to change now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.states').change(function(){
        var id = this.value;        
        $.ajax({
            type    : "POST",
            url     : "<?php echo base_url();?>Reports/Fetch_Item",
            data    :{'id':id,},                        
            success : function (data) {
                alert(data);
                var obj=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            }           
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: i have another doubt @ashokan

Comment: i getting some values and i have show it in the text box but i have 2 radio button  credit and debit if the "type" field is C credit should be checked and vice versa how it  writes in ajax success function

Comment: You can refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147012/set-radio-button-checked-with-ajax-response/30147287 , hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

The `$(this).val()` returns an array, you have to change your backend code to handle the array.

Something like below.

```
public function Fetch_Item(){
    $name = implode(",", $this->input->post('id'));
    $result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM acc_master WHERE accName in ('$name')")->rows();
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Note: `Fetch_Item` methon sql will return multiple results so you have to handle this as well.

Comment: in means it changes array value

Comment: It converts array to comma separated values. So then you can use this using `in`

Comment: sohail i have another doubt